# Stripe: Card not being declined on charge attempt (0341)

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, payment

I'm using the card 4000000000000341 in testing mode on Stripe.

This card supose to behave like this:

> Attaching this card to a Customer object succeeds, but attempts to charge the customer fail

Despite this, when I try to charge this source it succeeds. What could be happening?

Comment: This error may be specifically for charging the customer and not the source.  If you are making a charge and specifying `source`, try removing `source` and use the `customer` field instead.

Comment: ok, first of all I set the default_source of the subscription to the new source (0341), submit the changes and then, i'm creating an invoice by issuing the customer_id, finally call the pay method.

Comment: I think that is important to note that I was already perfoming transactions with this card number attached to a different customer and everything works as expected.

Comment: ok, I found out that the default source of the user whose the charge attempt works as expected, is (0341), on the other hand, the user whose charge attempt does not works as expects has a chargeable source as default. Maybe Stripe is doing a "best effort" aproach to charge the user?

Comment: If the customer has a default source (not the 0341 card) then that will be used as a primary source. Try to remove the default, or change it on the test dashboard.